# LUA unexpected symbol near ')'

Tags: lua, fivem

fivem

```lua
local loaded = false
    
function loadTxd(source, args, raw) 
    local txd = CreateRuntimeTxd('duiTxd')
    local duiObj = CreateDui('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/813996951066116097/854844624114548786/lcd_sign1.gif', 4096, 1024)
    _G.duiObj = duiObj
    local dui = GetDuiHandle(duiObj)
    local tx = CreateRuntimeTextureFromDuiHandle(txd, 'duiTex', dui)
    AddReplaceTexture('bus', 'lcd_sign_1', 'duiTxd', 'duiTex')
end)

Citizen.CreateThread function loadTxd(source, args, raw)
    while loaded == false do
        Wait(0)
        local playerCar = GetVehiclePedIsIn(GetPlayerPed(-1))
        if playerCar ~= 0 then
            if GetEntityModel(playerCar) == GetHashKey('bus') then
                loadTxd()
                loaded = true
            end
        end
        if not loaded then
            local veh = nil
            for veh in EnumerateVehicles() do
                if GetEntityModel(playerCar) == GetHashKey('bus') then
                    loadTxd()
                    loaded = true
                    break
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

says it lua5.3: ...Desktop/rextester_linux_2.0/usercode/29524824/source.lua:10: unexpected symbol near ')' but I can't find it anywhere I even tried deleting the whole line 10 and pasting all the code back in and then putting the end) on line 10

Answer (score 2):

There are a few syntax errors here:

- The extra `)` after `end` on line 10, which is the error you're seeing
- An opening parenthesis is missing after `Citizen.CreateThread`
- When you write `function foo(...)`, that's equivalent to writing `foo = function(...)`. You can't give a function a name when you're using it inline, like you are with the one you're passing to `Citizen.CreateThread`.

So, to fix the syntax errors, the middle part of your code (lines 10–12) should read:

```lua
...
end

Citizen.CreateThread(function(source, args, raw)
...
```